# Difference between these shared_ptr instantiations?

Tags: c++, templates, shared-ptr

I'm not so experience with templates, and I've found some usage in my team's code that has me confused.

Let's say I have a base class with the following two typedefs for shared_ptr:

```
class Foo
{
     virtual ~Foo();
     virtual void bar() = 0;
};

typedef boost::shared_ptr<Foo> FooPtr1;         //this is what i'm used to seeing
typedef boost::shared_ptr<class Foo> FooPtr2;   //this is in our codebase
```

Is there any difference between these typedef's? Is it related to usage with derived classes?

Comment: I'm sure this instantiations are the same.

Comment: Perhaps there's another `Foo` that isn't a `class` (a `struct` or `union`, or even a `const some_type Foo = ...`) that the code is trying to disambiguate...

Comment: @twalberg: Since [`class` and `struct` are interchangable](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8782dfe1587948f2) in this scenario, that wouldn't even help. Handy if you're desperate to error out immediately [if `Foo` were a `union`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d723de0b4e9bc4e8) or a value, though, yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no difference.

The syntax `class Foo` is supported for consistency with `struct Foo`, which in turn is supported for C compatibility. In C a `struct` is not a type by itself: the *type* corresponding to a struct called `S` is `struct S`, which is usually named via a `typedef`. In C++ the `typedef` isn't needed, and the syntax is largely irrelevant. I've found it useful for introducing "inline" tag types for template instantiations, like `X< whatever, struct X_tag >`, where the tag type is an incomplete type. But that's all.